# Debug Pyqt with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt6

I'm using PyCharm and running a script using the PyQt6 library. I'd like to know if it's possible to access properties like QLabel.text() or QLabel.isEnabled() while debugging? I want to see what's inside my QWidget, its state...

All I can see are properties like 'PaintDeviceMetric', 'RenderFlag', 'clicked'...
Is there a plugin to download? Or maybe it's not possible at all.

A small script to test, just in case: (In this case, during debugging , how can i have the QLabel.text() with pycharm)

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication,
    QLabel, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QListWidget, QLineEdit,
    QLineEdit, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider
)
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        widget = QLabel("Hello")
        font = widget.font()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        widget.setFont(font)
        widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Any standard IDE has an internal debugging system. You normally put break points and the IDE will normally provide an interface to inspect the current program status. Start by [reading the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Debugging_Code.html). Also consider that a basic debugging tool is to just print objects and their properties in specific points of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the point of my post is not how to debug, that i know. It's just that pycharm does not give me the information that i want (or i do not know how to access it). when i'm looking inside a variable (a QWidget) during debugging, I do not see the properties that i need.

Comment: `.text()` is not a property of your `QLabel`. The parentheses should make this clear. It's a method that returns the text of the label. That's why pycharm doesn't show it. An easy way to know what the values are at a given moment is just to insert a print: `print(my_label.text())`

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to PySide6 you can get methods like `text()` as properties.
Add this line to your imports:

```
from __feature__ import true_property
```

That will make the Qt getter and setter methods behave like python properties.
You can do things like:

```
my_label = QLabel()
my_label.text = "hello"
# instead of my_label.setText('hello')
```

It will also make `text` show in pycharm's variable view when debugging.